# Adobe Player stopped working on 2 of my machines. Error 2046. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-8.1, video, flash-player

About 3 weeks ago the Adobe Player stopped working on 2 of my Windows 8.1 Professional desktops. Interestingly enough it works fine on a 8.1 Pro laptop I've got. Anyway, each time I try to view a video on some web page where they're using Adobe, it always fails with error #2046.

Today I tried to resolve the issue. Went to Adobe's website to look for an answer for Windows 8.1 machines. That instructed me to uninstall Adobe Play. I did. Then I was to enable the Shockwave Player in IE. It is already enabled. Then I was to download and install the latest version of Adobe Player for Windows 8.1 64-bit machines. I tried, but it told me it's already installed.

And I still cannot play any video at all from whatever website that happens to use it to stream a video.

So how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I fix Adobe Player Error 2046?

You have a corrupt cache.

> 1. Clear your browser cache
> 2. Go to this URL http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html
> 3. Uncheck "Store common Flash components to reduce download times.".
> 4. Click confirm.
> 5. Re-check the box.
>
> This should flush any cached libraries on the Flash side.

Source [Error 2046 widespread problem?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1845923)